# LED undercabinet lights but 240v inputs 

Tags: lighting, kitchen-counters, led

I have replaced a run of halogen under cabinet lights with 1w lights running of an LED driver.

This string of LEDs goes under a run of wall cabinets over a worksurface.

I have two smaller worksurface areas that need only 1 light each.

Can I fit LEDs that have integral drivers. Seems silly to fit drivers that cost more to power 6 light and only use one with them.

Where would I get such LEDs with integral drivers (i.e. connect to 240v mains in UK)?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you should just get a transformer to transform your 240v main to whatever the LED drivers are looking for.  Without more detail, I'm not sure what the LED's are designed to take in.

It sounds like your LED drivers are going to convert a less-then-240 voltage AC feed down to the couple of volts DC that the LEDs are going to use.  Since you are putting these under cabinets, you could mount the transformer up and out of the way where you couldn't see it.

I'd look at one of the online electronic parts suppliers (like DigiKey or Jameco) to find the transformer you will need.  You shouldn't have to get to big of one since you are only powering LEDs.